# Custom view android onMeasure method shows double the value set in layout

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am trying to create own custom view ,I observed `onMeasure` shows into 2 of whatever value set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.customview.PercentageCircle
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:currentValue="0"
    custom:maxValue="100"
    custom:thickNess="80"
    custom:fillBackgroundColor="@color/light_gray"
    custom:fillColor="@color/red"
    />
```

```
 @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);//shows 200
        this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight); 
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

When I log the parentHeight or parentWidth ,I get double the specified value.I am not able to understand cause of it.

Comment: you have `android:layout_width="match_parent"` so how it can be "doubled"?

Comment: It is showing pixel value as you set 100dp in dp.

Comment: yes except match_parent and wrap_content it is getting doubled .

Comment: so specify `android:layout_height="123px"` and check again, if you get 123 then see what is the meaning of `dp`

Comment: yeh it is showing correct 123 ..

Comment: so now learn about [dp](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP)

Answer (score 1):

All the inputs to Canvas functions are in pixels. 
Function parameters of `onMeasure` are also in pixels.
To work UI across the devices , If we use pixels, things become too small on high resolution screens.

To convert from dp to pixels,

> float heightInPixel = getHeight()/ getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

Comment: This answer helped me, but I'm not sure that is accurate. getHeight() and getMeasuredHeight() provide pixel results, so dividing by the density will not give height in pixels, it will give height in points or dp.